# Css changes is not reflecting in Django

Tags: python, css, django

I'm doing a Django project, my issue is when I change colors in the style.css file in the static folder, the changes aren't reflected on the website, again the same old colors are coming.

[ScreenShot of my project file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8P8D.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike with Python files, Django doesn't automatically refresh the server each time a static file is updated. What most official sources recommend is running `py manage.py collectstatic`.

This often doesn't work (at least for me), but all CSS changes are usually implemented after a complete reboot.

So try saving, closing all your files, then restarting your computer. It's a simple workaround, but it's often reliable.